# Google App Engine: "The backend is locked down"

Tags: google-app-engine, authentication, authorization, backend, sample

I am trying to test out the Google App Engine. I have created an appspot domain, downloaded the sample project and put in all credentials required. I have also enabled Google Cloud Messaging for Android.

When I hit the send button (in the samples GuestBookActivity), I get the message:

"The backend is locked down. The administrator can change the authentication/authorization settings on [my appspot domain]".

Does anyone know about this issue and how to resolve it?

Comment: Are you using Mobile Backend Starter? See point 8.: https://developers.google.com/cloud/samples/mbs/deploy_backend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Peter Knego said, see point 8 here: https://developers.google.com/cloud/samples/mbs/deploy_backend

I had forgot to open my server for development use.