# Where are the unlock settings for google mobile backend started

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-platform

I have pretty much the same question as this [Google App Engine: "The backend is locked down"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19778139/google-app-engine-the-backend-is-locked-down) but I have an additional problem that the deploy button is hanging (over an hour) for some reason even though the backend is running. This means that point 8 here https://developers.google.com/cloud/samples/mbs/deploy_backend is impossible as I don't see the settings menu.

Can anyone help find an alternative way to get to the settings menu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it already. When refreshing the page the installing still hangs but the settings link pops up for a second - looked at the source code and the link was in there :)