# Google App Engine: "The backend is locked down" despite authentications in cloud console

Tags: authentication, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine, backend

I am having same issue as mentioned in this question ->
[Google App Engine: "The backend is locked down"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19778139/google-app-engine-the-backend-is-locked-down)

I have also set up all credentials and authenticated myself and able to login, but constantly get the message

```
 com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 401 Unauthorized
POST <my API url>
{
  "code": 401,
  "errors": [
    {
      "domain": "global",
      "message": "The backend is locked down. The administrator can change the authentication/authorization settings on <my site url>",
      "reason": "required"
    }
  ],
  "message": "The backend is locked down. The administrator can change the authentication/authorization settings on <my site url>"
}
```

The solution in the code mentions a link https://developers.google.com/cloud/samples/mbs/deploy_backend and mentions point 8, but that link does not seem to be same now in 2024.

How to solve this issue ?

Comment: can you have a look a this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25752765/where-are-the-unlock-settings-for-google-mobile-backend-started)